# inclusion or function? that is the question

Tags: php, function, optimization, server-side-includes

let me explain my question this way...
I have a piece of html block which I want to reuse it several times in my app.
here I have 2 choices...

number 1 is to define a function in my functions file and put the html code in that function. and every time I need the html I call the function.

number 2 is to write my html inside another file and every time I need it I include it in my script.

what I want to know is which way is faster and use less resources?

btw I use PHP but I don't think that is relevant. I think my question applies to other languages as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it would be faster to include it in a function. If you include the file each time it adds the overhead of needing to open and read the file; with a function it's just copying a bit of memory around.

I think that this is usually the case with PHP; certain servers and languages can be configured to optimize the include, but the function is almost always at least as fast.

Comment: but consider this if I use a function the memory has to carry it everywhere even when I don't need it but with includes I call it whenever I need it.

Comment: Ah, I was only thinking in terms of CPU, not memory. Hmm. A normal PHP script doesn't run very long, so holding the data in memory is probably not a problem in most cases, as it won't need the space for long. Perhaps the memory*time will even be lower, because it's faster. I wonder if there are any benchmarks like this...